# Trying to do insertion sort on java but doesnt work properly

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list, singly-linked-list, insertion-sort

Im trying to do insertion sort on Java.Here is my Node Class
`public class Node {
    private Object data;
    private Node link;

```
public Node(Object dataToAdd) {
    data = dataToAdd;
    link = null;
}

public Object getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Object data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public Node getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(Node link) {
    this.link = link;
}
```

}

`And here is my Single Linked List Class`
public class SingleLinkedList {
    Node head;

```
public void insert(Object dataToAdd) {
    Node newnode = new Node(dataToAdd);
    if (head == null) {

        head = newnode;
    } else {
        Node temp = head;
        Object[] data = ((String) dataToAdd).split(";");
        Object[] compare = ((String) temp.getData()).split(";");
        System.out.println(data[1]);
        if (Integer.valueOf((String) data[1]) < Integer.valueOf((String) compare[1])) {

            temp = head;
            head = newnode;
            newnode.setLink(temp);

        } else {
            temp = head;
            while (temp.getLink() != null)
                temp = temp.getLink();
            newnode.setLink(temp.getLink());
            temp.setLink(newnode);
        }

    }
}

public void display() {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.print(" ");

    } else {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.print(temp.getData() + " ");
            temp = temp.getLink();
        }
    }

}

public boolean previousCheck(char answer) {
    int count = 1;
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.print(" ");

    } else {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            if (answer == (char) temp.getData()) {
                count++;
            }
            temp = temp.getLink();
        }
        if (count > 2) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public Object get(int number) {
    if (head == null) {
        System.out.println("Linked is empty ");
        return null;
    } else {
        Node temp = head;
        while (temp != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
                temp = temp.getLink();
            }
            return temp.getData();
        }

    }
    return null;

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SingleLinkedList [head=" + head + "]";
}
```

}
`

> I need to be a new insert method for to doing insertion sort .
>   A file was read and input was that like Name;Score
>   My purpose is sorting these values by score points.
>   Everything seems OK.
>   However the output happened like that.
>   \n
>   Ece;5 Kaan;15 Pelin;30 Ali;50 Yeliz;25 Cem;40 Can;35 Sibel;30 Remzi;20 Nazan;10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the insert method a little bit, to be like that

```
public void insert(Object dataToAdd) {
    Node newNode = new Node(dataToAdd);
    if (head == null) {
        head = newNode;
    } else {
        int score = getScore(dataToAdd);
        int headObjectScore = getScore(head.getData());
        if (score > headObjectScore) {
            Node temp = head;
            head = newNode;
            newNode.setLink(temp);
        } else {
            Node currentNode = head;
            //to handel if the newNode has the biggest score
            if(currentNode.getLink()==null){
                currentNode.setLink(newNode);
                currentNode = newNode;
            }
            while (currentNode.getLink() != null){
                Node oldNode = currentNode;
                currentNode = currentNode.getLink();
                if(score>getScore(currentNode.getData())){
                    oldNode.setLink(newNode);
                    newNode.setLink(currentNode);
                    break;
                }
                //to handel if the newNode has the biggest score
                if(currentNode.getLink()==null){
                    currentNode.setLink(newNode);
                    currentNode = newNode;
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
private int getScore(Object data){
    return Integer.valueOf(((String) data).split(";")[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this works fine. This code sorting from small number to bigger, but how can I convert it from bigger  number to small?

Comment: Everything is ok. I'm very grateful for your help.